Certain apps in Ubuntu do not show in dark theme Yaru-dark
Environment: Ubuntu 23.10, Wayland, AMDGPU, 2013 Apple MacPro Trashcan.
I tried the following potential solutions:

"I had the same issue after running my automated system-customisation
scripts on a fresh Ubuntu-23.10 installation. After hours of research
and experimentation I solved the problem for my case, but found that
other people had the exact same or similar symptoms due to other
cause, so here I've summarised all potential fixes that I've learned:
Potential Solutions
uninstall all incompatible gnome extensions, even if they are disabled
disabling all extensions is recommended when troubleshooting anyway
run the following shell commands (or edit the settings manually in the
dconf-editor):
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.ubuntu color-scheme prefer-dark
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru-dark
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
check the contents of the folders ~/.config/gtk-3.0 ~/.config/gtk-4.0
Change gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=0 to
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
Make sure the xdg-desktop-portal-gnome and xdg-desktop-portal packages
are installed. I found in Manjaro forums that that OS had a Gnome 45
issue with the exact same symptoms described here, which they could
fix by installing those packages. I think they're installed by default
on Ubuntu-23.10, though."

Additionally i have org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru-dark and Adwaita-dark flatpak themes installed.
For me in Ubuntu 23.10 but certain apps still refuse to show dark mode and completely ignore whatever gtk settings I force, for example:
Don't show dark mode with Ubuntu .deb install:

Nautilus
Calendar
Gnome-Software center
Gnome-Settings



Apps that show dark mode in my case Yaru-dark

dconf editor
gnome tweaks
disks



Don't show dark mode with Flatpak install

flatseal
tuba
space launch (even when switching to dark mode via app setting)


Apps that show darkmode

geary


Are you applying the themes to both 'shell theme' and 'legacy application theme'? If yes, open the folder of the theme you've installed, go to the gtk4.0 folder, copy all of it's content and paste it into .config/gtk4.0. Do not delete the default files in gtk4.0, just paste your theme files in it.

Ok just did that and in the ~/.config/gtk4.0 folder I also updated the .ini file to: [Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
gtk-icon-theme-name=Yaru
gtk-theme-name=Yaru-dark  I will reboot and let you know what it looks like.

OMG Noble Eugene You saved the day. There was no solution online describing what you just did. I have no idea how my system got to the state in the first place. All the applications now show in dark mode!

You're welcome @CaptainCook. It's apparently an issue with many themes not being fully supported in gtk4. Copying the files to the config folder should help most of the time.
